# How can I configure vite or esbuild such that it does NOT emit /* @__PURE__ */ annotations?

Tags: vite, esbuild

vite emits javascript code with /* @**PURE** */ annotations for jsx code parts. How can I configure it so it avoids that?

Searched through vite issues at github but did not find anything.

Comment: I have the same question. From what I have read, pure functions are marked as such so that the compiler can remove them if they aren't used. Unsure. But building for format: `es` leaves the code littered with the annotations even in production mode.